# rgl - how to spin two opened devices

Tags: r, rgl

On the webpage [rgl Overview](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/vignettes/rgl.html) there's the following example of using `mfrow3d` to open two rgl devices and control them from the same mouse. However, if `play3d(spin3d())` is used, only the last of the two devices spins.

```
library(MASS)
# from the fitdistr example
set.seed(123)
x <- rgamma(100, shape = 5, rate = 0.1)
fit <- fitdistr(x, dgamma, list(shape = 1, rate = 0.1), lower = 0.001)
loglik <- function(shape, rate) sum(dgamma(x, shape=shape, rate=rate, 
                                           log=TRUE))
loglik <- Vectorize(loglik)
xlim <- fit$estimate[1]+4*fit$sd[1]*c(-1,1)
ylim <- fit$estimate[2]+4*fit$sd[2]*c(-1,1)

mfrow3d(1, 2, sharedMouse = TRUE)
persp3d(loglik, 
        xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim,
        n = 30)
zlim <- fit$loglik + c(-qchisq(0.99, 2)/2, 0)
next3d()
persp3d(loglik, 
        xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, zlim = zlim,
        n = 30)
```

Is there a way to get both images to spin at the same time?

Comment: Atm, I don't think that this is possible out of the box. You can just select on of both subscenes e.g. using `play3d(spin3d(subscene = subsceneList()[1]))` or `play3d(spin3d(subscene = subsceneList()[2]))`.

Answer (score 0):

The current development version of rgl (0.95.1476, only available on R-forge, see [How do I install the latest version of rgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142762)) now does this by default.  You can also control subscenes that don't share a mouse, e.g.
by code like

```
play3d(spin3d(subscene = subsceneList()))
```