# How do I install the latest version of rgl?

Tags: rgl

The `rgl` package used to be developed on R-forge at https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rgl/.  The way to install the latest version was

```
install.packages("rgl", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

but this is no longer valid.  What's the current way to install the latest version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(This has been updated since rgl moved from R-forge to Github).

The simplest way is to install from Github, using

```
devtools::install_github("dmurdoch/rgl")
```

This installs a version that may be a few hours old.  It does require that you have the tools for a source install; `rgl` has a lot of code that needs to be compiled.  Those tools are available for Windows at https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. Full OSX installs require XCode and XQuartz and perhaps some other packages.  Linux users will need to install a number of libraries as well.  Both OSX and Linux support minimal installs that only work with `rglwidget()`.

You can also check out from Github using

```
git clone https://github.com/dmurdoch/rgl.git
```

Then you can install it using

```
R CMD INSTALL rgl
```

(provided all the prerequisites exist).

Comment: Oddly - seems odd to me anyway - it requires svn to be installed. Why would that be?

Comment: Which of the three methods are you talking about?  It doesn't seem odd that using svn requires svn, but the other methods don't need it.

Comment: The first. It is really strange. Will post as a question.

Comment: Posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281755/why-do-i-need-svn-to-install-rgl-from-github

Comment: Interestingly that question generated a lot of comments - somewhat heated comments.

Comment: Also when I finally did get it installed from the github mirror, it seems the version was out of date (0.95.1494 whereas my already installed version was 0.96.0)  https://github.com/rforge/rgl/blob/master/pkg/rgl/DESCRIPTION

Comment: It appears that the Github mirror hasn't been updated since July, 2016.  I've edited the answer to leave out the Github possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't upvote the answer anymore so upvoted the question :).

Comment: solves the problem with crashing RStudio on loading the `rgl` package