# Why do I need SVN to install rgl from github using install_github?

Tags: r, devtools, rgl

It was surprising to find `install_github` failing with a message "SVN does not seem to be installed on your system" indicating that SVN was needed. This followed the advice from a well-known `rgl` installation question [How do I install the latest version of rgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142762/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-rgl/37142971#37142971). I could install it manually, but I did not understand the message and posted the question in the title.

After some messy investigation we found that it was due to a `remote` configuration line in the `rgl` package DESCRIPTION file that was not needed. This answer is in the comments to the answer marked correct.

However we also found that much of the guidance in the original question was out-of-date and it has since been modified.

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Rforge is not Github. If I google "github rgl" the first link description literally says "A copy of the RGL SVN repository". Now, do you need to install SVN to install rgl? I don't think so. Just install from the github mirror if that is up-to-date. Can you use `install_github` for installing from Rforge? Apparently not, but that's a minor inconvenience at most.

Comment: Well, user2554330 was surprised, and he should know. He is not just any user.

Comment: I am happy to delete this post if the consensus is that it is trivial.

Comment: If I wanted to install rgl from source, I'd download the source from CRAN. If I wanted to install the development version, I would install SVN (actually, I already have it installed) and get it directly from R-Forge.

Comment: I know that, that is not the point. The point is that the instructions that said user posted are misleading, and I was seeking to clarify it. If it is intended to be that way, than so be it.

Comment: Once he takes a look I will delete it, ok?

Comment: The repo is an SVN repo. If you follow the chain of functions from `install_github` you'll see that an S3 generic with an SVN method gets called. You need SVN to install an SVN repo. Obviously, you could just download the source manually.

Comment: Acutally, shouldn't the `subdir="pkg/rgl"` parameter point `install_github` at something it can install alone? Looks like a standard R package directory to me. Should not need SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:  the Github mirror is up to date again, so all of the methods listed in [How do I install the latest version of rgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142762/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-rgl/37142971#comment69764517_37142971) should be fine.  If the server dies again, you can always use
`install.packages()` or use SVN.

The `install_github()` method should no longer require an SVN install.

Comment: Yes, also there is a remote dependency in the DESCRIPTION file that demands SVN to install `rglwidget`. I suppose that was a later addition and the reason for the puzzling error message.

Comment: The current `rgl` doesn't need `rglwidget`, and no longer has that remote dependency.

Answer (score -1):

You can install from RForge and any other SVN repo using the proper *SVN* variant of `install_github()`.  The devtools package has `install_svn`, and so do the lighter-weight alternatives such as the remotes packages.

But in all these cases you still need ... an SVN client to download from an SVN repo. Which makes some sense.

What you can do, however, using just git is to use the *read-only mirror every CRAN package has on GitHub*.  For rgl the [GitHub mirror repo is here](https://github.com/cran/rgl) and I would expect to be successful in using `install_github` against that repo.

Comment: I understand all that, but `install_github("rforge/rgl,subdir="pkg/rgl")` is pointing at an R package. If I grab that directory I can install it locally fine. Why is it even triggering SVN? Seems like what was recommended should work - think it probably did and then it broke.

Comment: "Doctor doctor it hurts when I do this."  The stop doing it.  _If you insist on using `install_github()`_ then I would use the GH repo instead.  But I already told you that.

Comment: Also note that you confuse http://r-forge.r-project.org (a SVN repo) with http://rforge.net (something else, run by Simon).  The rgl is on the former.

Comment: I didn't mention either of those. I mentioned `http://github.com/rforge`.

Comment: And I am not in any pain. I am just trying to understand why something that apparently used to work does not work anymore.

Comment: You are making a heroic assumption that the world owes you _every CRAN package_ as a GitHub install.  Ever considered that assumption may not hold?  Ever wondered why CRAN has tarballs?

Comment: `install_github()` is a contributed hack, even if it is widely used. It's not official channel.  So if it breaks _you_ may need to debug it.  The picture is getting a little clearer now (if it worked before).  I am done here; if you have new questions ask a new question.  Good luck.