# Transparency with RGL

Tags: r, transparency, rgl

I have trouble using transparency with RGL.
I have a numeric variable ("Plague"), two binary variables ("Fortune" and "Have diamonds"). I make a regression of the two binary variables on the numeric one "plague ~ fortune + diamond".

To illustrate this, I want to draw the points in 3D, then draw the regression plan. MI want the plan to be transparent, but it is not! I tried with the alpha channel, also with adjuscolor. I get a false transparency: The color of the plan change as if it was transparent, but we can not see through. Do you know how I can get real transparency with rgl?

Here is my code

```
set.seed(13)
dn <- expand.grid(id=1,Fortune=c("Riche","Pauvre"),Diamant=c("Oui","Non"))
dn <- dn[rep(1:4,times=c(50,5,10,100)),]
n <- nrow(dn)
dn$id <- 1:n
dn$Plague <- round(runif(n,0,ifelse(dn$Fortune=="Riche",10,30)),1)

library(rgl)
plot3d(dn$Fortune,dn$Diamant,dn$Plague,xlim=c(0.8,2.2),ylim=c(0.8,2.2),zlim=c(0,50),
  axes=TRUE,xlab="",ylab="",zlab="")

triangles3d(x=c(0.8,0.8,2.2),y=c(0.8,2.2,2.2),z=c(2,9,23),col=adjustcolor("red",0.3),alpha=0.3)
triangles3d(x=c(2.2,2.2,0.8),y=c(2.2,0.8,0.8),z=c(23,16,2),col=adjustcolor("red",0),alpha=0.3)
```

Thanks for your help!

Christophe

Comment: I see through the surface, so I'm not sure what problem you're having.  Maybe you're using an old version of `rgl` where there were some bugs with this?  The latest is available from R-forge:  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142762/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-rgl

Comment: I just download the last version of R and RGL. I try using linux and windows: The problem is still here.
Note that the transparency works just fine for the cube (the axis xX, yY and zZ), but does not works for the points. The points behind the red triangles are hidden.

Comment: What version number of rgl are you using?  I see the problem you describe with 0.98.1 from CRAN, but not with the latest version from R-forge.

Comment: Yes, you're right: I am using the version from CRAN.
I am not sure that I know how to get the version from R-Forge... Is it possible to download it?

Comment: See my first message for instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and thanks for the link. It works. The red triangle is now transparent.
Only one problem left: it seems that it has no effect on black color. I mean:black through the red triangle is still black. I do not know why, but I was expecting something different (like in real life, if I see a black object through some red transparent paper, the black will be different than a regular black)

Anyway, in my case, I changed my black into darkgrey dot and then is works.

Comment: The CRAN version has been updated today, so this should now be fixed without going to R-forge.

Answer (score 1):

OK - I know that the question is a bit dated...

It seems... to set transparency in rgl you need to modify the 'material' in which the object is displayed. This is done through:

```
 material3d()
```

So to set the transparency of color 1 (black) to 80%

```
 material3d(1,alpha=0.2) # with alpha = 1-0.8
```