# Capture coordinates through shiny + rgl

Tags: r, shiny, rgl

Is it possible to use identify3d() or something similar to capture the coordinates of landmarks in an rgl scene rendered through renderRglwidget? I'm using the following code in shiny to render:

```
#server
observeEvent(input$mspec3D, {
    tt1 <- out2[[6]][out2[[6]][,3] == input$mspec3D, ][1]
    tt1 <- as.numeric(tt1)

    tt2 <- out2[[6]][out2[[6]][,3] == input$mspec3D, ][2]
    tt2 <- as.numeric(tt2)

    tt1 <- out2[[1]][[tt1]]
    tt2 <- out2[[1]][[tt2]]

    output$webgl3D <- renderRglwidget ({
        try(rgl.close())
        points3d(tt1, size=3, col="dimgray", box=FALSE)
        points3d(tt2, size=3, col="dodgerblue", box=FALSE)
        axes3d()
        rglwidget()
    })
})

#ui
rglwidgetOutput('webgl3D', width = "1200px", height = "400px")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though it's only in the development version at the moment.  You can get that from R-forge or Github, see [How do I install the latest version of rgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142762/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-rgl).  You need to use [crosstalk](https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/).

See the discussion in the WebGL vignette in the development version of `rgl`.

Comment: Is this the WebGL vignette you were referring to?
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/vignettes/WebGL.html

I see it allows a selection of points but not individual points. Are there any plans to expand that to more than just a general selection?

Comment: You aren't looking at the development version.  These changes are not released yet.

Comment: Even in the development version there isn't much more information on this.....Looks like something similar to identify3D has not been mentioned.

Comment: That's what crosstalk does.  Read its web page (which was linked) to see how to use it in Shiny.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for.  Could you modify your original question so it will run by a simple cut and paste (don't assume I know Shiny), and describe what you want it to do that `identify3d()` could do but `crosstalk` can't?