# Xaringan plotly not rendering: A website is slowing down your browser what would you like to do

Tags: r, windows, rgl, htmlwidgets, xaringan

I'm trying to debug an OS specific error with `xaringan` (an issue with plotly) . I was able to create the following `xaringan` manhattan plot with the `manhattanly` package on a Linux and Mac OS at work earlier today but it's not rendering on my Windows at home.

```
{r, echo = FALSE, results = TRUE, error = FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.width=15, fig.height=5}
if (!requireNamespace("manhattanly")) {
  install.packages("manhattanly")
} else {
  library(manhattanly)
}
manhattanly(HapMap, snp = "SNP", gene = "GENE", highlight = significantSNP)
```

This is my `yaml` in the RMarkdown:

```
---
title: "Main title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: "Matthew J. Oldach"
date: "2019-02-28"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      ratio: 16:9
    css: ["default", "custom.css"]
---
```

And my options chunk:

```
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

First of all the strange thing is when I create standard `ggplot` graphs (or any xaringan slide-deck that works, for example, the `leaflet` example) I only see a large white screen with a small box in the top left. However, when I hit the "show in browser" it displays. Another SO post suggested running `xaringan::summon_remark()` to fix this but it did not work for me.

Nonetheless, when trying to view the code posted above on windows I get a error/message in Firefox:

> A website is slowing down your browser what would you like to do?

If I try opening this in internet explorer, chrome the same thing. As I mentioned earlier other plots, slides, *etc.* render, and the above worked on Linux and Mac OS earlier today.

A somewhat longer example of another plot that worked on Linux and Mac OS at work but not on windows is the following:

```
if (!requireNamespace("widgetframe")) {
  install.packages("widgetframe")
} else {
  library(widgetframe)
}
if (!requireNamespace("rgl")) {
  install.packages("rgl")
} else {
  library(rgl)
}
if (!requireNamespace("misc3d")) {
  install.packages("misc3d")
} else {
  library(misc3d)
}
if (!requireNamespace("neurobase")) {
  install.packages("neurobase")
} else {
  library(neurobase)
}
if (!requireNamespace("aal")) {
  devtools::install_github("muschellij2/aal")
} else {
  library(aal)
}
if (!requireNamespace("MNITemplate")) {
  devtools::install_github("jfortin1/MNITemplate")
} else {
  library(MNITemplate)
}

img = aal_image()
template = readMNI(res = "2mm")
cut <- 4500
dtemp <- dim(template)

# All of the sections you can label
labs = aal_get_labels()

# Pick the region of the brain you would like to highlight - in this case the hippocamus_L
hippocampus = labs$index[grep("Hippocampus_L", labs$name)]

mask = remake_img(vec = img %in% hippocampus, img = img)

### this would be the ``activation'' or surface you want to render
contour3d(template, x=1:dtemp[1], y=1:dtemp[2], z=1:dtemp[3], level = cut, alpha = 0.1, draw = TRUE)
contour3d(mask, level = c(0.5), alpha = c(0.5), add = TRUE, color=c("red") )
### add text
text3d(x=dtemp[1]/2, y=dtemp[2]/2, z = dtemp[3]*0.98, text="Top")
text3d(x=-0.98, y=dtemp[2]/2, z = dtemp[3]/2, text="Right")
l <- rglwidget()
frameWidget(l)
```

Feedback greatly appreciated.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.2  htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.5.2     xaringan_0.8    yaml_2.2.0     
 [6] Rcpp_1.0.0      rmarkdown_1.11  knitr_1.21      xfun_0.5        digest_0.6.18  
[11] evaluate_0.13
```

Comment: The CRAN version of `rgl` is getting kind of old; a fair number of bugs have been fixed in the R-forge version.  If your problems are related to `rgl`, you might want to try it instead.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37142762/2554330 to install it.

Comment: If you are seeing unexpected results in a particular browser, it's useful to look at the browser console for error messages.  In RStudio one way to get that is to right click on the bad display, choose "Inspect Element" from the popup menu, then click on "Console" in the list of tabs that appears in the RStudio display.

Comment: Try updating to the newest version (development version) of `xaringan` on your Windows machine. Could that be the culprit?