# rgl mouse wheel affects only last subscene

Tags: r, rgl

`rgl::mfrow3d` Allows one to plot multiple subscenes in the same rgl window.

Clicking and dragging on a subscene rotates the scene, as expected. 
However, scrolling the mouse wheel zooms only the last subscene. Is there a way to zoom the scene on which the mouse is on with the mouse wheel?

A simple example can found in the documentation:

```
shapes <- list(Tetrahedron = tetrahedron3d(), Cube = cube3d(), Octahedron = octahedron3d(),
               Icosahedron = icosahedron3d(), Dodecahedron = dodecahedron3d(),
               Cuboctahedron = cuboctahedron3d())
col <- rainbow(6)
open3d()
mfrow3d(3, 2)
for (i in 1:6) {
  next3d()   # won't advance the first time, since it is empty
  shade3d(shapes[[i]], col = col[i])
}
highlevel(integer()) # To trigger display as rglwidget
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the subscene you want to resize?  After I do that the mouse wheel works on that one.

Comment: @user2554330 Yes, I have tried that; still, only the last shape resizes. (If this information is helpful, I am running R 3.6.1 on windows x64, rgl version 0.100.30)

Comment: That bug was fixed in 0.100.33.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37142762/2554330 for where to get it.

Comment: @user2554330 Great, thanks for the solution. Would you like to convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the CRAN release of `rgl` (version 0.100.30).  It should be fixed in the development version (0.100.33 or later).   See [How do I install the latest version of rgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37142762/2554330) for where to get it.

With the fixed version, the mouse wheel affects the subscene where the mouse was last clicked, rather than the last one created.

Comment: also impacts digit.fixed.Thanks for the solution.