# Control fog density in rgl

Tags: r, rgl

I am looking for a way to change the overall fog density of an rgl scene (there is no parameter to directly do this, and all fogtype=... choices are way too dense)
Any tips?
Thanks!

Comment: Fog depends on depth into the scene.  You could reduce it by moving your objects closer to the viewer.

Comment: Show us a reproducible example.  I can't seem to get fog to be very dense at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the development version 0.102.9.  For example, this code
gives the standard fog:

```
library(rgl)
shade3d(cube3d(), col = "black", lit = FALSE)
bg3d(fogtype = "exp", col = "white")
```

After some rotation, you see this:

[image: screenshot with regular fog]

If you then run this:

```
bg3d(fogtype = "exp", col = "white", fogScale = 0.5)
```

the plot darkens to this:

[image: screenshot with fogScale = 0.5]

To get this development version, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142971/2554330.